# application.visible=true multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, hide

I'm making a program for a lady at my work that will allow her to save a unique ID and the name of a PDF. When she enters the unique ID#, it will open the PDF that she needs to print off for the customer.

My current issue is that I want to hide the workbook from her or anyone else who will use the program. The best code I've seen so far to accomplish this is to use the `Application.Visible = True`. However, I have multiple workbooks open and I imagine some of the other people who use it will too.

Is there a way to specify which workbook I wish to affect? Every time I try to add one in any way, it gives me a debug error. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.Visible
```

hides / shows the complete (current) Excel application object. To hide only one workbook you may want to try

```
Workbooks("TheBookIWantToHide").Windows(1).Visible = False
```

However I find it a bit dangereous to hide books or applications that are "in use". When the VBA gets stuck you may end up with loads of orphaned Excel processes sitting in the background.

I'd recommend a strategy whereby you have one "printing book" containing the VBA logic and one "ID book" containing the latest unique ID. After entry of an ID and validation open the ID book in VBA in a new application object (hidden), save the ID, store and close the ID book

Comment: I tried your code and it did work like I needed it to, so I appreciate it. I also think your right about it causing issues. It was no longer closing all instances of Excel, but I was having all kinds of issues with it. I think I may just leave the workbook up in the back ground and protect it. I just don't think it looks as good that way. @MikeD

Comment: You may consider hiding sensitive sheets within a given workbook and optionally protect them from being unhidden by a password (downside: you may have to code this PW in VBA to open it via code) ... for average non-violent (*ggg*) use I find plain hiding without password good enough.

Comment: I think I will try that. I don't think the users will actively try to cause harm and I want to be able to create backups at some point. It was mainly to keep them from accidently opening the 'Master' sheet and deleting the entire database.